# Mediawiki Sitemap URL restricted by robots.txt

Tags: web-crawler, mediawiki, sitemap, bots, robots.txt

I have installed the mediawiki on my site like this: `www.mysite.com/w/index.php`

I have used the Short URL method to change the url to `mysite.com/wiki`

After that, I placed this in the robots.txt to disallow bots to follow links to `/w/`:

```
# prevent spiders from indexing non-article pages
User-agent: *
Disallow: /w/
```

I refered to this Mediawiki Manual link here before I added the above to robots.txt: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Robots.txt

This is useful since it prevents bots from crawling the edit pages, etc.. etc.. But ever since I have that, now I have another problem that is showing in google webmaster tools. The search engine is unable to crawl my sitemap that is located in: `mysite.com/w/sitemap/sitemap-index-xyz_wikidb.xml` This is because of the robots.txt file that is showing "URL restricted by robots.txt" error.

I have been searching on the net and realised that there is no "allow" exception for robots.txt file. So how can I disallow /w/ urls but allow access to only `/w/sitemap/ directory`? Is my only other option is to disalllow individual urls like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /w/index.php?diff=
Disallow: /w/index.php?oldid=
Disallow: /w/index.php?title=Help
Disallow: /w/index.php?title=Image
Disallow: /w/index.php?title=MediaWiki
Disallow: /w/index.php?title=Special:
Disallow: /w/index.php?title=Template
Disallow: /w/skins/
```

If the above alternative method is my only option, is this how I add the urls by adding `/w/` before each of the index.php urls?? like: `/w/index.php?etc..etc..` and list the above one my one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only care about major search engines, you can use the Allow directive:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /w/sitemap/
Disallow: /w/
```

This will definitely work for Googlebot and Bingbot. It will not work on many older robots, however. The Allow directive is not part of the original robots.txt standard, but it is implemented on many modern web robots, especially search engine crawlers.

If you really need it to work for older robots as well, then your solution will work. You can also clean this up a bit by combining all of the index.php URLs into one line:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /w/index.php
Disallow: /w/skins/
```

Comment: Just found this: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt

Comment: I second the suggestion to use `Allow:`. You _could_ also just move the sitemaps outside the `/w/` directory, but it turns out that there are also other paths under `/w/` that you'll probably want to allow search engines to access, such as `/w/images/` (to allow image indexing) and perhaps also `/w/load.php?` (for CSS / JS).